# Getting only new items from AngularFire list

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I'm implementing a chat app using a Firebase RTDB list. Here's a simplified data service implementation:

```
public monitorConversation(conversationId): Observable<any> {
  return this.afDB.list(`/conversations/${conversationId}/messages`).stateChanges();
}
```

Then I call it from a component (page) like:

```
msgList: Observable<any>;
this.msgList = this.dp.monitorConversation(conversationId);

this.msgList.subscribe(message => {
  console.log('new msg:', message.payload.val());
    return message.payload.val();
  });
});
```

The desired outcome is that each time a new message gets added to the conversation, I get the new message. What is happening is that I'm getting the entire list of messages. My fear is that as the message list grows, UI performance will start suffering since I'm having to re-display the list, AND the bandwidth that it consumes sending unnecessary traffic, since I assume the entire list is being retrieved from the Firebase as well.

Is there a way to only receive changed or new items? Items have $keys in the list so I do know which item is which.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, it is possible:

**Firebase Realtime database**

```
this.rtdb
    .list('path', ref => ref.orderByChild('timestamp').startAt(Date.now()))
    .stateChanges();
```

**Firebase Firestore**

```
this.afs
    .list('path', ref => ref.where('timestamp', '>', new Date()).orderBy('timestamp'))
    .stateChanges();
```

> You can also use `limitToLast` or `limit` to get a newest item, regarding angularfire2 official [doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/querying-lists.md#creating-a-query-with-primitivescalar-values).

Comment: Thank you. I think I have discovered a bug in AngularFire2 that I'm trying to replicate. If you have more than one subscription on a list (not a query), for some reason changes to the list return all the records. Once I unsubscribed from another Observable that was watching the same list, it stated working.